# UIButton touch on UITableViewCell detected only on far left side

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have an UIButton and i have assigned a UIImage to it. The UIButton is on my UITableViewCell and it detects a touch only if i tap on the left top side of the UIButton! Is anyone had this issue before? Any help appreciated.

This is my code:

```
     UIButton *indicatorlabel =
            [[UIButton alloc]
             initWithFrame:
             CGRectMake(280,20,22,22)];
            indicatorlabel.tag = INDICATOR_LABEL_TAG1;

            UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture24449 =[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelTapShare:)];
            [indicatorlabel addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture24449];
            [indicatorlabel setTitle:@"shareit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            indicatorlabel.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=TRUE;
            indicatorlabel.userInteractionEnabled=TRUE;
 [indicatorlabel setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Share.png" ] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 [cell.contentView addSubview:indicatorlabel];
```

No other view is overlaying the UIButton i have checked it.

Thanks

Comment: indicatorlabel.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=TRUE;
Use YES, this is the first observation.

Comment: thanks for your answer danutz Ch...Sorry i was wrong i have created another UILabel at the same coordinates.

Comment: You are adding a tapGestureRecognizer to a UIButton. You can just assign a target/action to your button and use it to capture a touch instead of using an UIGestureRecognizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys i was wrong i have created another UILabel at the same coordinates.